# 2 return flows in TS and only one is found in autocompletion

Tags: typescript

I don't figure out why TS can't infer the types of the 2 flows in this example :

```
function toto(mode: boolean) {
    if (mode) {
        return [42]
    } else {
        return "mike"
    }
}

const test = toto(true) // const test: number[] | "mike"
const test2 = toto(false) // const test2: number[] | "mike"
```

Test it in the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFOKAUBbOATApgLkQCM44AbXAQzAEpEBvAKERcRmEUx1zqdf8QAnXFBCCkAbQAsAJgC6zVgF9EuMgGdcDRQKEixSAEQYYAa1yGdiJYxuMICdVGS4niALzJUcNFEEgee0dnKFcoGQ8vdGBKDUDGIA).

Why the auto completion puts only the array methods and not the string ones (like toUpperCase) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function return type can only be of one type, so Typescript is merging both flows,..  `number[] | 'mike'`  In a lot of cases this is what you might want.

But you can do function overloads, this will then mean you can have different return types for different inputs.

eg..

```js
function toto(mode: true):number[];
function toto(mode: false):'mike';
function toto(mode: boolean) {
    if (mode === true) {
        return [42]
    } else  {
        return "mike"
    } 
}

const test = toto(true)
const test2 = toto(false)
```

Be aware that in Typscript literal string types are narrowed, so `'const a = 'hello'` is not of type string, it's of type `'hello'`.  So if you want `mike` to be of type string you could do this->

```js
function toto(mode: true):number[];
function toto(mode: false):string;
function toto(mode: boolean) {
    if (mode === true) {
        return [42]
    } else  {
        return "mike" as string
    } 
}

const test = toto(true)
const test2 = toto(false)
```